Why frequency deviation in BLE 1Msym is different than BLE 2Msym?
From Bluetooth Core spec:

The modulation is Gaussian Frequency Shift Keying (GFSK) with a bandwidthbit period product BT=0.5. The modulation index shall be between 0.45 and 0.55. A binary one shall be represented by a positive frequency deviation, and a binary zero shall be represented by a negative frequency deviation.
…
The minimum frequency deviation shall never be less than 185 kHz when transmitting at 1 megasymbol per second (Msym/s) symbol rate and never be less than 370 kHz when transmitting at 2 Msym/s symbol rate.

Why not keeping the 185kHz deviation for 2 Msym/s, too? Does it have anything to do with the smaller bit period and the sampling/demodulation on the receiver side?

You cut out the important part of the standard that specifies which frequency deviation we're talking about here!

Let's look at the specs from the top. The modulation index being ca. 0.5 means that Fmin+ - Fmin- = 0.5 Fsymbols.
That makes a lot of sense – that is Minimum shift keying, i.e., it's the smallest possible modulation index that still allows a positive- and a negative-frequency symbol to be orthogonal under correlation as inner product.
Since Fmin+ - Fmin- = 0.5 Fsymbols and  Fmin+ = -(Fmin-) it follows that |Fmin+| = |Fmin-| = 0.25 Fsymbols.
For 1 MBd, that's 250 kHz, for 2 MBd, that's 500 kHz.
Now, remember that this is the frequency deviation "calculated" for each data bit before the pulse-shaping filter. Put the bit sequence 0101 (and respectively -1,+1,-1,+1 "frequency multipliers", if you will) through the implementation of your Gaussian pulse shaping filter, and you will see that the heights of your symbols are reduced by the pulse shape (this is not a filter that fulfills the Nyquist ISI criterion!).
So, this measure effectively puts limits on the quality of your implementation of the pulse-shaping filter.

Thank you for the answer. Probably I am missing some knowledge here. I don't get the "orthogonal under correlation as inner product." From my perspective the rf signal will be downconverted in the receiver at a small frequency (e.g. 1MHz) plus/minus the freq deviation and then it is about the ADC and the demodulator on the baseband to sample and demodulate the bits.

You'll want to read up on "Minimum Shift Keying" then.
